# enumerateDates discrepancy when enumerating backward?

Tags: swift, date, xcode11

A strange discrepancy happens between enumerating a day of the month between two dates forward or backward. I get the correct answer when enumerating forward, but enumerateDates jumps inexplicably when enumerating backward.

Lets try and enumerate dates between 2020 and 1980:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 1980
dateComponents.month = 1
dateComponents.day = 1
dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")
dateComponents.hour = 8
dateComponents.minute = 0
let stopDate = cal.date(from: dateComponents)
dateComponents.year = 2020
dateComponents.month = 1
dateComponents.day = 1
let startDate = cal.date(from: dateComponents)
if let stopDate = stopDate {
    if let startDate = startDate {
        var comps = DateComponents()

        //Lets enumerate forward first

        print("Enumerating forward")
        for dotm in 1..<32 {
            var counter = 0
            comps.day = dotm
            comps.hour = 8
            cal.enumerateDates(startingAfter: stopDate, matching: comps, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward) { (date, match, stop) in
                if let date = date {
                    counter += 1
                    if date > startDate {
                        print("number of months with day \(dotm) in month: \(counter)")
                        counter = 0
                        stop = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //And do the same thing backward

        print("Enumerating backward")
        for dotm in 1..<32 {
            var counter = 0
            comps.day = dotm
            comps.hour = 8
            cal.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startDate, matching: comps, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward) { (date, match, stop) in
                if let date = date {
                    counter += 1
                    if date < stopDate {
                        print("number of months with day \(dotm) in month: \(counter)")
                        counter = 0
                        stop = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Lets inspect closer

        print("What is happening?")
        comps.day = 1
        cal.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startDate, matching: comps, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward) { (date, match, stop) in
            if let date = date {
                print("Date found: \(date)")
                if date < stopDate {
                    stop = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Enumerating forward
number of months with day 1 in month: 481
number of months with day 2 in month: 481
number of months with day 3 in month: 481
number of months with day 4 in month: 481
number of months with day 5 in month: 481
number of months with day 6 in month: 481
number of months with day 7 in month: 481
number of months with day 8 in month: 481
number of months with day 9 in month: 481
number of months with day 10 in month: 481
number of months with day 11 in month: 481
number of months with day 12 in month: 481
number of months with day 13 in month: 481
number of months with day 14 in month: 481
number of months with day 15 in month: 481
number of months with day 16 in month: 481
number of months with day 17 in month: 481
number of months with day 18 in month: 481
number of months with day 19 in month: 481
number of months with day 20 in month: 481
number of months with day 21 in month: 481
number of months with day 22 in month: 481
number of months with day 23 in month: 481
number of months with day 24 in month: 481
number of months with day 25 in month: 481
number of months with day 26 in month: 481
number of months with day 27 in month: 481
number of months with day 28 in month: 481
number of months with day 29 in month: 451
number of months with day 30 in month: 441
number of months with day 31 in month: 281
Enumerating backward
number of months with day 1 in month: 189
number of months with day 2 in month: 189
number of months with day 3 in month: 189
number of months with day 4 in month: 189
number of months with day 5 in month: 189
number of months with day 6 in month: 189
number of months with day 7 in month: 189
number of months with day 8 in month: 189
number of months with day 9 in month: 189
number of months with day 10 in month: 189
number of months with day 11 in month: 189
number of months with day 12 in month: 189
number of months with day 13 in month: 189
number of months with day 14 in month: 189
number of months with day 15 in month: 189
number of months with day 16 in month: 189
number of months with day 17 in month: 189
number of months with day 18 in month: 189
number of months with day 19 in month: 189
number of months with day 20 in month: 189
number of months with day 21 in month: 189
number of months with day 22 in month: 189
number of months with day 23 in month: 189
number of months with day 24 in month: 189
number of months with day 25 in month: 189
number of months with day 26 in month: 189
number of months with day 27 in month: 189
number of months with day 28 in month: 189
number of months with day 29 in month: 177
number of months with day 30 in month: 174
number of months with day 31 in month: 111
What is happening?
Date found: 2019-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 2019-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 2019-10-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1995-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1994-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1993-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1992-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1991-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1990-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1989-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1988-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1987-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1986-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1985-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1984-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1983-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1982-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-04-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-03-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-02-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1981-01-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-12-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-11-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-10-01 07:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-09-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-08-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-07-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-06-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1980-05-01 06:00:00 +0000
Date found: 1976-04-01 07:00:00 +0000
```

When counting backward there is a strange jump from 2019 to 1995 and again from 1980 to 1976. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in enumerateDares? I am using Xcode 11.3.

Update:

The behavior of enumerateDates when enumerating backwards is even stranger. When we change startDate, the counting is sometimes correct. A quick check of all the possible start days in January 2020 gives us the following matrix (the first column being startDate, the second column the number of days with dateComponents.day = 1, the third column dateComponents.day = 2, etc ...)

```
2020-01-01 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 177 174 111
2020-01-02 482 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 177 174 111
2020-01-03 482 482 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 177 174 111
2020-01-04 482 482 482 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 177 174 111
2020-01-05 482 482 482 482 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 177 174 111
...
2020-01-27 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 189 189 177 174 111
2020-01-28 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 189 177 174 111
2020-01-29 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 201 177 174 111
2020-01-30 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 201 189 174 111
2020-01-31 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 482 201 189 174 111
```

So maybe enumerateDates only counts correctly if the first hit is in the current month?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which occurs always after the date is set to October 1st.

Please file the bug as I did a few weeks ago, unfortunately Apple didn't respond yet.